# I tried to add a scroll bar to my table python, but it doesn't work

Tags: python, tkinter

I had made a python array that worked very well, except that afterwards I wanted to add a scroll bar.
Can you help me please.

Here is my code

```
from tkinter import *

fen = Tk()
fen.geometry('1500x800')
fen.grid()

tableau1 = Frame(fen, width=1100, height=700,)
tableau1.config(background="#45B39D")
tableau1.grid_propagate(0)

tableau1.place(x=10, y=50)


data = [["NOM","Prénom","DS1","TP2","IE4"],["Coef","",4,0.5,1],["frfrf","Bruno",20,14,3],["Hardelepique","Helmut",10,6,"abs"],["NOM","Prénom","DS1","TP2","IE4"],["Coef","",4,0.5,1],["frfrfr","Bruno",20,14,3],["Hardelepique","Helmut",10,6,"abs"],["NOM","Prénom","DS1","TP2","IE4"],["Coef","",4,0.5,1],["frfrfr","Bruno",20,14,3],["Hardelepique","Helmut",10,6,"abs"],["NOM","Prénom","DS1","TP2","IE4"],["Coef","",4,0.5,1],["frfrfrf","Bruno",20,14,3],["Hardelepique","Helmut",10,6,"abs"],["NOM","Prénom","DS1","TP2","IE4"],["Coef","",4,0.5,1],["frfrfr","Bruno",20,14,3],["Hardelepique","Helmut",10,6,"abs"],["NOM","Prénom","DS1","TP2","IE4"],["Coef","",4,0.5,1],["frfrfr","Bruno",20,14,3],["Hardelepique","Helmut",10,6,"abs"],["NOM","Prénom","DS1","TP2","IE4"],["Coef","",4,0.5,1],["frfrfr","Bruno",20,14,3],["Hardelepique","Helmut",10,6,"abs"],["NOM","Prénom","DS1","TP2","IE4"],["Coef","",4,0.5,1],["frfrfr","Bruno",20,14,3],["Hardelepique","Helmut",10,6,"abs"],["NOM","Prénom","DS1","TP2","IE4"],["Coef","",4,0.5,1],["frfrfr","Bruno",20,14,3],["Hardelepique","Helmut",10,6,"abs"]]


class tableau:
    def __init__(self, tableau1):

        h = Scrollbar(tableau1, orient='horizontal')
        h.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
        v = Scrollbar(tableau1)
        v.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)

        for i in range(total_rows):
            for j in range(total_columns):

                self.e = Text(tableau1, width=10, height=1.2, fg='blue',font=('Arial',16))#, xscrollcommand=h.set, yscrollcommand=v.set)
                self.e.grid(row=i, column=j)
                self.e.insert(END, data[i][j])
                self.e.config(state="disabled")

        self.e.pack(side=TOP, fill=NONE)
        h.config(command=self.e.xview)
        v.config(command=self.e.yview)


total_rows = len(data)
total_columns = len(data[0])

tableau(tableau1)

fen.mainloop()
```

I managed to put in "Text", I have no more errors! But it's showing me something weird.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to include the _full_ error messages. We can't help you (since we don't know whether the error messages we're getting are the same ones you're getting) if you don't tell us exactly what's wrong. Please read [ask] for more information on asking good questions.

Comment: Ok, that's edit

Comment: Thanks. This error is caused because `Entry` doesn't have a `yscollcommand` option. Change `Entry` to `Text` to fix this. Even then, however, there will be a whole ton of other problems with the code that you'll need to fix.

Comment: This is painful because I do not know how to make this beautiful picture with Text... 
And I added "array1.place(x=10, y=50)" in the code because otherwise even without the scroll you could not see the array

Comment: Ok! I managed to put in "Text", I have no more errors! But it's showing me something weird.

Comment: I have edit my first post